# how to write a subset with a condition that a value exists multiple times (just like SQL IN operator)

Tags: r, subset

I'm trying to subset a data-frame with the condition that a specific column contains few specific userID.

```
subset(df, df$userID===100 & df$userID===101 & df$userID===104 & df$userID===106)
```

Now, I don't want to write a statement like this with multiple conditions and wonder if there's a shortcut to do it, something like the SQL statement

> ...WHERE userID IN (100,101,104,106).

Later, my goal is to have something like this:
userIDs<-c(100,101,104,106) and integrate it in the subset.

Comment: With operator `%in%`. See `help("%in%")`

Comment: YES! works like a charm. Thanks. write it as an answer and I'll check it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the operator `%in%` like in this example :

```
1:10 %in% c(1,3,5,9)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```